# Is reference itself a lvalue?

Tags: c++

I saw an answer about lvalue yesterday, what below is its content:

> — An lvalue (so called, historically, because lvalues could appear on
>   the left-hand side of an assignment expression) designates a function
>   or an object. [ Example: If E is an expression of pointer type, then
>   *E is an lvalue expression referring to the object or function to which E points. As another example, the result of calling a function
>   whose return type is an lvalue reference is an lvalue. —end example ]

so a question comes out: is reference itself a lvalue?
I know that both lvalue-reference and rvalue-reference can appear on the left-hand side of an assignment expression, but reference is neither function nor object, is there a contradiction? And Is reference really a lvalue?
Moreover, if a reference is a lvalue, what's the type of decltype(reference-expression), for example:

```
int main (void) { int a = 1; int &b = a; decltype((b)) c; }
```

what's the type of c?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the expression `b` is an lvalue, with type `int`.

The declaration of `c` is the same as `int &c`. (So it's ill-formed since you didn't provide an initializer). If you did provide an initializer, the expression `c` is an lvalue with type `int`.